# How to access Twitter media urls using academictwitteR?

Tags: r, twitter, rtweet

I have a Twitter API for Academic Research and would like to retrieve the media urls (images and videos) from tweets in `R` using the `academictwitteR` package. This is possible using the `rtweet` package. See an example below:

Using `rtweet`:

```
tweets_war_noir <- search_tweets("war_noir", n=10, parse = FALSE, include_rts=TRUE, retryonratelimit = TRUE)
twee_war_noir_picture_url <- tweets_war_noir$extended_entities$media %>% sapply(function(x) ifelse(nrow(as.data.frame(x))>0, x$media_url %>% str_subset("ext_tw_video_thumb", negate=T) %>% paste(collapse=" | "), NA))
```

Using `academictwitteR`, not quite:

```
tweets_war_noir <– get_all_tweets(users = "war_noir",start_tweets = "2021-01-01T00:00:00Z", end_tweets = Sys.Date() %>% paste0("T00:00:00Z"),bearer_token = get_bearer(), n = 10)
```

It is only possible to retrieve the `media_id` attribute, which I could not relate to any url. Any any suggestion on how to proceed?

Comment: Use rtweet? BTW, I think you could get it easier with `parse = TRUE' and later use `rtweet::entity(tweets_war_noir,  entity = "media")$media_url`. But if recall correctly the media_id could be used to create a url ( I don't remember now how but you might find examples on the web)